# Rails blog list all categories in navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a simple blog with categories and posts nested within a category.

I want to build the navigation to list all the categories from my category model and list all the posts from this category.

From the posts index page I have the below link which goes to foobar.com/categories/id and its displays all the posts correctly but I cant figure out how to get this to work so that no matter what page a user is looking at they can see the navigation and click on a category to view its show page with all posts associated with the category.

```
<%= link_to post.category.title, category_path(post.category) %>
```

Comment: What do you mean globally?

Comment: Ah, sorry for not being clearer. I have a partial for the nav so no matter what page of the site a user is viewing they will see the categories and can view all posts on the category show page. Just updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show links to all the categories, you could do this.

```
<% Category.all.each do |category| %>
  <%= link_to category.title, category_path(category) %>
<% end %>
```

Note: As the number of categories grows, this will not look good on a navbar

Comment: The admin only wants 5 categories but I wanted to make them dynamic so they could be changed or removed rather then hardcoding them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want categories to be accessible from anywhere in the site you'll have to define them inside the `application_controller.rb`

```
@categories = Category.all
```

and then on your nav partial you can do something like this:

```
<% @categories.each do|category| %>
  <%= link_to category.title, category_path(category)%>
<% end %>
```